# How to stop GhostDoc adding punctuation to the end of the line

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ghostdoc

Whilst there is a lot a like about GhostDoc, I've never liked the fact that it adds a full stop to the end of each comment in the tag. Is there a hack to turn this off?

[image]

I say "hack" as I've already checked the options and I can't see anything that looks like it might assist.

I'm running version 4.9.15086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these can't be turned off at this point.

Comment: What. a. shame.